# How can i convert bash curl request to python

Tags: python, curl

I am a beginner in python. So, below is my code. This was originally written in bash and now I want to write an equivalent code for this in python. However, I cannot wrap my head around it. Please help.

I have a config file called config.py where all the variables are defined. For this particular context, both apimessage and reportingapi are variable which is being called from config.py

I have imported it in the main.py. When i print them directly, they get printed but inside this curl command, it does not.

Thanks in advance.

```
def encoding_complete():
    
    response = request.post(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null -d **apimessage** -X POST **reportingapi**)
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you read requests example and docs ?

Comment: @azro I tried going through many documentation but haven't got a clue as how to find a workaround

Comment: I suggest starting with something simple. First try to get a web page from a given url. Then try to post data to a url. Continue building up from there.

Comment: First, know what each curl option does. Then find the equivalent parameter to use in `request.post(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your main problem is you can't run bash commands in python. You need to have another library `subprocess` for that.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("your bash command goes here as a string")
```

refer [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

If your bash command is correct it would do. You can't `request.get` and `curl` inside it.

Comment: That is a great workaround for thi sissue.

Answer (score 0):

@J.Smith Thanks. Your solution pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: Np. If it solved it can you accept my answer?